# How to create placeholder with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, placeholder

[image]I want to create form like above attached image. Can add placeholder to text box. But when user press keys placeholders missing. I need to show placeholders above the text box when key press inside the text box.

Comment: What have you tried? Show examples of code that is not working. StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `html` `required`, `autofocus` and `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+$|$)` to match one or more `a-z` characters case insensitive at beginning of input, followed by space character, followed one or more `a-z` characters case insensitive by end of input, or end of input to handle two first names, for example `"Billy Joe"`, `"Norma Jean"`,  `"Sarah Jane"`; `<label>` element adjacent to `<input>` element; `css` `:invalid`, `:valid`, `:before`; `:after`.

When `input` is `:invalid` set `border` to `red`, `outline` to `none`; set adjacent `label` element `:before` `content` of  to `"das"`, `label` `:after` `content` to `!`; at `:valid:focus` set `label` `:before` `content` to `"First Name"`, `label` `:after` to `UTF-8` `"CHECK MARK"` `✓`

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
#input {
  height: 3.14em;
  left: 0px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 150px;
}
#input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-shadow: .015em .015em .015em green;
}
#input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: .015em .015em .015em red;
}
#input:invalid + [for="input"]:before {
  content: "das";
}
#input + [for="input"]:after {
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 160px;
  top: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}
#input:invalid + [for="input"]:after {
  content: "!";
  color: red;
}
#input:valid + [for="input"]:after {
  content: "\2713";
  color: green;
}
#input:valid + [for="input"]:before {
  content: "First Name";
  color: #ccc;
}
label[for="input"]:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<input id="input" type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+$|$)" required autofocus/>
<label for="input"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#lbl{
  color:green;
}
#in{
  border:none
}
#in,#in_container,#lbl{
  background:white
}
#in_container{
  display:inline-block;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="in_container">
<span id="lbl">First Name</span>
<br>
<input type='text' id="in">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS magic:

```css
.input-group * {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.input-group input {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.input-group label {
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="first-name" type="text">
  <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
</div>
```

Basically, just play around with the sized until you get a solution working for you. I'd group each "input box" section, they are composed of a label superimposed onto a text input.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container * {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#my-input {
  height: 30px;
}

#lbl-my-input {
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: absolute;
  color: #bebebe
}

#my-input:focus {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label id="lbl-my-input" for="my-input">First</label>
  <input id="my-input" type="text">
</div>
```

Here is my idea:

- I put the label and  the input in a div
- I make div position relative, label position absolute => label will overlapped input
- I use css for input:focus. When focusing happens, I extend padding-top of input.
- The rest is styling (choosing) right line-height, font-size, and padding to make it beautiful

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this.

```html
<label style="visibility: hidden;" id="label">User Name</label>
<input id="textField" type="text" placeholder="User Name" onfocus="showLabel()" onblur="hideLabel()"></input>
<script>
    function showLabel() {
        var label = document.getElementById("label");
        var textField = document.getElementById("textField");
        textField.placeholder="";
        label.style.visibility = "inherit";
    }
    function hideLabel() {
        var label = document.getElementById("label");
        var textField = document.getElementById("textField");
        textField.placeholder="User Name";
        if (!textField.value) {
            label.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
</script>
```